# Looking for all available options of Gutenberg Block

Tags: block-editor

I am trying & learning to build custom block for Gutenberg but spent a few hours on searching for full list of "available options". Maybe I was overlook...

Refer: [Template and Block](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-templates/)

For example, `placeholder` & `align` are options but what else?

```
function myplugin_register_book_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Books',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'template' => array(
            array( 'core/image', array(
                'align' => 'left',
            ) ),
            array( 'core/heading', array(
                'placeholder' => 'Add Author...',
            ) ),
            array( 'core/paragraph', array(
                'placeholder' => 'Add Description...',
            ) ),
        ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_register_book_post_type' );
```

Example 2:
those empty `array()` should be allow to store some options, right?

```
$template = array(
    array( 'core/paragraph', array(
        'placeholder' => 'Add a root-level paragraph',
    )),
    array( 'core/columns', array(), array(
        array( 'core/column', array(), array(
            array( 'core/image', array() ),
        )),
        array( 'core/column', array(), array(
            array( 'core/paragraph', array(
                'placeholder' => 'Add a inner paragraph'
            )),
        )),
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Option 1

Browse the [`block-library` package](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src) in the Gutenberg's GitHub repository, and find the block metadata in a JSON file named `block.json` of the specific block. For example, for the `core/image` block, you can find the metadata (e.g. all available/supported attributes) [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/image/block.json):

```
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/image/block.json
```

So basically, the URL format is:

```
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/{name}/block.json
```

where `{name}` is the block name without the `core/` part.

### Option 2 (PHP)

For blocks registered using the PHP/WordPress function `register_block_type`, you can use this to get the block attributes:

```php
$block = WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_registered( 'core/latest-posts' );
$attrs = $block ? $block->get_attributes() : [];
var_dump( $attrs, $block );
```

### Option 3 (JavaScript)

For blocks registered using the JavaScript function `wp.blocks.registerBlockType`, you can use this to get the block attributes:

```js
var block = wp.blocks.getBlockType('core/gallery');
var attrs = block ? block.attributes : {};
console.log( attrs, block );
```

Comment: It’s a little bit annoying that after almost 1/2 year since publishing Gutenberg in WP, there documentation for it is still as bad... :(

Comment: wonderful answer and information! Detail and helpful, so glad to have you replied the question and wish it helps other as well.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, indeed.. :/ And the `block.json` is actually a new thing. In the previous Gutenberg releases, the block attributes are saved in `blockAttributes` but not in all block (the main `index.js`).

Comment: @kevinckc, I hope so, too! And +1 for the helpful question. :)